# Why does cryptsetup segfault?

Tags: linux, segmentation-fault

While most of my [use a `chroot`ed Gentoo as supplement to another Linux distribution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/99084) project works fine, unfortunately `cryptsetup` segfaults on both `luksFormat` and `luksOpen`. How to troubleshoot this best?

**edit[** For testing purposes I downgraded the Firmware to an older version which runs a 2.6.31 Kernel instead of a 3.3 one, and there the segfault does not occur. Nonetheless I would like to get this working with the newer version, so any help on troubleshooting this is appreciated...

**edit2** Following [this hint](http://buffalo.nas-central.org/wiki/Enable_Encrypted_Partitions_for_LS-VL), I compared the output of `grep dm_crypt /proc/kallsyms` and noticed that the newer Kernel lacks `__initcall_dm_crypt_init6` - could this be reason of failure? How can that be fixed?
**]**

An `strace | tail` reveals

```
open("/dev/loop0", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 6
ioctl(6, BLKRAGET, 256)                 = 0
close(6)                                = 0
ioctl(3, DM_DEV_CREATE, 0x3cfb0)        = 0
ioctl(3, DM_TABLE_LOAD <unfinished ...>
+++ killed by SIGSEGV +++
```

that `ioctrl(3, DM_TABLE_LOAD` seems to be responsible, where `3`, according to a `grep '= 3$'` should stem from

```
open("/dev/mapper/control", O_RDWR|O_LARGEFILE) = 3
```

so there is some trouble with `/dev/mapper/control`, where `/dev` is bind-mounted from the host system into the `chroot` environment. But what exactly is the problem? How can one figure that out?

---

Additional output, the usefulness of which I couldn't determine yet:

`cryptsetup --debug -v`'s output is not very informative:

```
# cryptsetup 1.4.3 processing "cryptsetup --debug -v luksFormat /dev/loop0"
# Running command luksFormat.
# Locking memory.

WARNING!
======== This will overwrite data on /dev/loop0 irrevocably.

Are you sure? (Type uppercase yes): YES
# Allocating crypt device /dev/loop0 context.
# Trying to open and read device /dev/loop0.
# Initialising device-mapper backend, UDEV is disabled.
# Detected dm-crypt version 1.5.1, dm-ioctl version 4.22.0.
# Timeout set to 0 miliseconds.
# Iteration time set to 1000 miliseconds.
# Interactive passphrase entry requested. Enter LUKS passphrase: Verify passphrase:
# Formatting device /dev/loop0 as type LUKS1.
# Crypto backend (gcrypt 1.5.3) initialized.
# Topology: IO (512/0), offset = 0; Required alignment is 1048576 bytes.
# Generating LUKS header version 1 using hash sha1, aes, cbc-essiv:sha256, MK 32 bytes
# PBKDF2: 43251 iterations per second using hash sha1.
# Data offset 4096, UUID 03dcff20-158e-4d16-b89c-90af7b176a80, digest iterations 5250
# Updating LUKS header of size 1024 on device /dev/loop0
# Reading LUKS header of size 1024 from device /dev/loop0
# Adding new keyslot -1 using volume key.
# Calculating data for key slot 0
# Key slot 0 use 21118 password iterations.
# Using hash sha1 for AF in key slot 0, 4000 stripes
# Updating key slot 0 [0x1000] area on device /dev/loop0.
# DM-UUID is CRYPT-TEMP-temporary-cryptsetup-12060
# dm create temporary-cryptsetup-12060 CRYPT-TEMP-temporary-cryptsetup-12060 OF   [16384] (*1)
# dm reload temporary-cryptsetup-12060  OFW    [16384] (*1) Segmentation fault
```

Finally, the systrace from the host's `/var/log/messages` reads

```
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel: Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address e58c20f0
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel: pgd = cab58000
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel: [e58c20f0] *pgd=00000000
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel: Internal error: Oops: 5 [#1]
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel: Modules linked in: usblp usb_storage uhci_hcd ohci_hcd ehci_hcd usbcore usb_common
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel: CPU: 0    Not tainted  (3.3.4-88f6281 #1)
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel: PC is at async_encrypt+0x44/0x50
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel: LR is at async_encrypt+0x48/0x50
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel: pc : [<c01fa374>]    lr : [<c01fa378>]    psr: 20000013
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel: sp : c10bfd60  ip : cc372580  fp : c10bfd84
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel: r10: d0a75160  r9 : d0a75175  r8 : 00000000
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel: r7 : c2f78428  r6 : 00000020  r5 : c2f783c0  r4 : e58c2040
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel: r3 : c94a72a0  r2 : 00000040  r1 : 00000000  r0 : c10bfd64
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel: Flags: nzCv  IRQs on  FIQs on  Mode SVC_32  ISA ARM  Segment user
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel: Control: 0005397f  Table: 0ab58000  DAC: 00000015
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel: Process cryptsetup (pid: 5994, stack limit = 0xc10be270)
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel: Stack: (0xc10bfd60 to 0xc10c0000)
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel: fd60: c023eddc c01fab50 00000010 c01f88f8 c030e4c8 00000000 c10bfdac c10bfd88
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel: fd80: c030e564 c01fa340 c2f783c0 00000040 c2f783c0 d0a75175 d0a7a020 d0a75164
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel: fda0: c10bfdcc c10bfdb0 c030e61c c030e50c d0a75168 00000000 c2f783c0 d0a75168
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel: fdc0: c10bfe1c c10bfdd0 c030fbcc c030e598 d0a75160 c00d262c c10bfe0c c7752a40
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel: fde0: c00dd198 00000000 d0a7516e 00000000 c030feb4 00000020 cebc9200 c2f783c0
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel: fe00: d0a7a020 00000005 00000000 cebc9500 c10bfe64 c10bfe20 c030fedc c030f9ec
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel: fe20: c10bfe64 c10bfe30 c0308148 c023d270 c10bfe64 00000040 d0a7a020 000000fa
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel: fe40: 000000fa d0a7a020 cebc9500 d0a75150 00000000 cebc9500 c10bfe9c c10bfe68
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel: fe60: c0308954 c030fe7c 00000000 00000000 cebc9200 00000005 000000fa 00000000
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel: fe80: 00000001 d0a75000 d0a79000 c10bfeb0 c10bfee4 c10bfea0 c030b57c c03087b0
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel: fea0: 000000fa 00000000 d0a75160 00008004 d0a75160 d0a75138 c0308b5c 00004000
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel: fec0: cb637c00 d0a75000 00000000 c030b604 c10be000 00008004 c10bff0c c10bfee8
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel: fee0: c030b678 c030b52c 00000016 cebc9500 c10be000 00000000 0003cf80 00004000
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel: ff00: c10bff3c c10bff10 c030c5c4 c030b614 c00fb8b4 d0a75000 cb4580a0 0003cf80
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel: ff20: c138fd09 cb4580a0 c000bca8 00000000 c10bff4c c10bff40 c030c65c c030c4c8
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel: ff40: c10bff5c c10bff50 c00f06b4 c030c654 c10bff7c c10bff60 c00f0e10 c00f0694
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel: ff60: c10bff8c c10bff70 00000003 0003cf80 c10bffa4 c10bff80 c00f0fbc c00f0db0
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel: ff80: c10bffa4 00000000 00000001 b6f93cc8 b6e22e80 00000036 00000000 c10bffa8
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel: ffa0: c000bb00 c00f0f8c 00000001 b6f93cc8 00000003 c138fd09 0003cf80 b6e31450
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel: ffc0: 00000001 b6f93cc8 b6e22e80 00000036 0003cfb0 0003cec0 b6e22e80 0003cf80
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel: ffe0: b6e2f0f4 bedcbbfc b6e1e880 b6f083bc 60000010 00000003 e2433001 e5863000
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel: Backtrace: 
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel: [<c01fa330>] (async_encrypt+0x0/0x50) from [<c030e564>] (crypt_setkey_allcpus+0x68/0x8c)
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel:  r4:00000000
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel: [<c030e4fc>] (crypt_setkey_allcpus+0x0/0x8c) from [<c030e61c>] (crypt_set_key+0x94/0xb8)
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel:  r8:d0a75164 r7:d0a7a020 r6:d0a75175 r5:c2f783c0 r4:00000040
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel: [<c030e588>] (crypt_set_key+0x0/0xb8) from [<c030fbcc>] (crypt_ctr_cipher+0x1f0/0x490)
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel:  r6:d0a75168 r5:c2f783c0 r4:00000000
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel: [<c030f9dc>] (crypt_ctr_cipher+0x0/0x490) from [<c030fedc>] (crypt_ctr+0x70/0x2fc)
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel: [<c030fe6c>] (crypt_ctr+0x0/0x2fc) from [<c0308954>] (dm_table_add_target+0x1b4/0x350)
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel: [<c03087a0>] (dm_table_add_target+0x0/0x350) from [<c030b57c>] (populate_table+0x60/0xe8)
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel:  r9:c10bfeb0 r8:d0a79000 r7:d0a75000 r6:00000001 r5:00000000
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel: r4:000000fa
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel: [<c030b51c>] (populate_table+0x0/0xe8) from [<c030b678>] (table_load+0x74/0x1f4)
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel: [<c030b604>] (table_load+0x0/0x1f4) from [<c030c5c4>] (ctl_ioctl+0x10c/0x18c)
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel:  r7:00004000 r6:0003cf80 r5:00000000 r4:c10be000
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel: [<c030c4b8>] (ctl_ioctl+0x0/0x18c) from [<c030c65c>] (dm_ctl_ioctl+0x18/0x1c)
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel: [<c030c644>] (dm_ctl_ioctl+0x0/0x1c) from [<c00f06b4>] (vfs_ioctl+0x30/0x44)
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel: [<c00f0684>] (vfs_ioctl+0x0/0x44) from [<c00f0e10>] (do_vfs_ioctl+0x70/0x1dc)
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel: [<c00f0da0>] (do_vfs_ioctl+0x0/0x1dc) from [<c00f0fbc>] (sys_ioctl+0x40/0x68)
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel:  r5:0003cf80 r4:00000003
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel: [<c00f0f7c>] (sys_ioctl+0x0/0x68) from [<c000bb00>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x2c)
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel:  r7:00000036 r6:b6e22e80 r5:b6f93cc8 r4:00000001
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel: Code: e24b0020 e59c1024 e59c2020 e1a0e00f (e594f0b0) 
Nov 14 14:02:15 host kernel: ---[ end trace 3c58c565608fcd8c ]---
```

Ok, so it's an "Oops: 5", the meaning of which I don't know...